# OpenCart 3.0 (3.x) + Authorize.net - how to disable ONLY the Authorize.net E-mail?

Tags: opencart, authorize.net

We currently accept credit cards by phone (entering the order info into the Virtual Terminal) as well as on the website (OpenCart, using the built-in Authorize.net AIM module).

Problem: when order is placed on website, the customer receives 2 E-mails - 1 from our site, 1 from Authorize. The Authorize E-mail, being plaintext, looks ugly AF, and my boss wants to have it disabled.

Attempt # 1: looked in the Authorize.net AIM plugin/module settings. No such option.

Attempt # 2: in the Authorize.net account, under "Settings -> E-mail Receipt", there is a checkbox "Email transaction receipt to customer (if email address is provided)".

Result #2:  unfortunately, this disables ALL transaction E-mails - from website transactions (OK) and from Virtual Terminal phone-order transactions (NOT cool). We have to provide an E-mail receipt to phone customers.

Attempt #3: in the OpenCart system, editing file:

```
catalog/controller/extension/payment/authorizenet_aim.php
```

to comment out the line

```
$data['x_email'] = $order_info['email'];
```

Result #3: during checkout, even if a valid E-mail is entered, upon trying to submit the order, the "Email address is required" error message appears.

So...
Can't disable it in Authorize plugin/module in OpenCart.
Can't disable it in Authorize Account Settings.
Can't just delete the E-mail from the array of data that OpenCart collects during checkout.

How can I disable the Authorize.net E-mail (and ONLY the Authorize.net E-mail, I still want the website receipt to go out) on a site built on OpenCart 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution (via Authorize.net Developers Forum). Simpler than I expected:

1. Open file: public_html/catalog/controller/extension/payment/authorizenet_aim.php
2. Find line: $data['x_relay_response'] = 'false';
3. Add after: **$data['x_email_customer'] = 'false';**

This allows the checkout process to complete without errors, and sends the transaction to Authorize.net along with the instruction to not E-mail the customer.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution but could you change the email address that gets sent to Authorize.net to be the store admin email, in that case it won't give you the "Email address is required" error message and you'll get that email instead of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

In attempt number 3, can you confirm whether OpenCart gives the error about the email being required or if Authorize.Net gives that error? If Authorize.Net provides the error it may be reconciled by adjusting the payment form settings in Authorize.Net:
1. Sign into Authorize.Net
2. Account > Payment Form > Form Fields
3. Make sure the email field isn’t checked as required.
4. Save your changes at the bottom of the page

Comment: It's the checkout page itself, before the transaction is submitted. But it doesn't matter, I found the solution, will post in a second.